# CCUserDefault, ios/android game and game updates

Tags: ios, save, cocos2d-x

My game uses cocos2d-x and will be published on iOS platform first, later on Android. I save a lot of things with CCUserDefault (scores, which level was completed, number of coins taken, etc...). But now i have a big doubt.
What will happen when the game will receive its first update?
CCUserDefault uses an xml file stored somewhere in the app storage space. This file is created and retained until one uninstall the app. I am wondering what happens when the app is updated. Will the old xml file mantained?
Because if not, how should i handle app updates (updates in the sense that 2,3 or more new level packages will be added, but the informations about the old ones, like scores, which level was finished and which not, number of coins etc..., need absolutely not to be lost)?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As much I know normally they not reset on update, you need to delete the app. What I think what you need at your first/previous update that you make some setting which signify/tell about version and if it not equal to recent one than update your NSUserDefualt with some basic setting or say reset your setting.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found the answer. CCUserDefault stores the xml file under:

> application_home/library/caches

The iOS App Programming Guide states that all the data under

> application_home/document
>
> application_home/library

will be preserved. That is, after the update, your userdefault.xml file will be still there.